# How to break down time spent across hours into minutes per hour?

Tags: r, datetime, google-sheets, time

I have a source table of start and end times at various stations. I would like to create a new table that shows all 24 hours possible and how many minutes each station logged per hour. There will be multiple dates and stations, but I'm including just one date and one station for this example. How do I create the desired result (see image) where hours are broken down by minutes from the start and end time values given in the source? I'm trying to conceptualize this in Google Sheets before replicating in R

Here is a sheet with the data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10zFTTsF1-VbKX6bvXP5PUjrTnJH49mWuzdMkTqfXQUY/edit#gid=0

[Start Time / End Time table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAJTt.png)

[Desired Result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz6kx.png)

```
Station Name    Started Time    Ended Time  Hours
station_1   2021-02-04 6:02:43  2021-02-04 8:04:43  2.03
station_1   2021-02-04 8:04:44  2021-02-04 8:39:43  0.58
station_1   2021-02-04 8:58:48  2021-02-04 10:30:11 1.52
station_1   2021-02-04 11:05:08 2021-02-04 11:24:14 0.32

Date Hour   station_1 Minutes
2021-02-04 00:00:00 
2021-02-04 01:00:00 
2021-02-04 02:00:00 
2021-02-04 03:00:00 
2021-02-04 04:00:00 
2021-02-04 05:00:00 
2021-02-04 06:00:00 0:57:17
2021-02-04 07:00:00 1:00:00
2021-02-04 08:00:00 0:36:11
2021-02-04 09:00:00 1:00:00
2021-02-04 10:00:00 0:29:49
2021-02-04 11:00:00 0:19:06
2021-02-04 12:00:00 
2021-02-04 13:00:00 
2021-02-04 14:00:00 
2021-02-04 15:00:00 
2021-02-04 16:00:00 
2021-02-04 17:00:00 
2021-02-04 18:00:00 
2021-02-04 19:00:00 
2021-02-04 20:00:00 
2021-02-04 21:00:00 
2021-02-04 22:00:00 
2021-02-04 23:00:00
```

Comment: Ok added to the post and here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10zFTTsF1-VbKX6bvXP5PUjrTnJH49mWuzdMkTqfXQUY/edit#gid=0

Comment: Hello there @benjamin! After considering your question I recommend you to create an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) to programatically create the desired outcome. Would that be a valid solution in your environment?

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing it in R with the lubridate and purrr packages

Comment: Congratulations @benjamin That is impressive. Could you please create an answer that describes how you did it?

Answer (score 0):

seems like you could just create a sql view to analyze your first table and return the information you're looking for in that format instead of trying to save it in another table.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but I'd like to create the second table because I want to visualize of all hours possible during the day, which hours the stations are being logged into

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution in R using the `lubridate` and `purrr` packages. It doesn't work for time periods spanning multiple days for example a duration that goes from 11 PM to 1 AM, but for single date analysis it works.

```
df1 <- df0 %>%
  select(station_name, started_time, ended_time) %>%
  mutate(started_time = round_date(ymd_hms(started_time), 'minute'), ended_time = round_date(ymd_hms(ended_time), 'minute')) %>%
  mutate(started_time = as.character(started_time), ended_time = as.character(ended_time)) %>%
  mutate(hour = (purrr::map2(hour(started_time), hour(ended_time), seq, by = 1)), started_date = date(started_time)) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(hour)  %>%
  mutate(minu=case_when(hour(started_time)!=hour & hour(ended_time)==hour ~ 1*minute(ended_time),
                        hour(started_time)==hour & hour(ended_time)!=hour ~ 60-minute(started_time),
                        hour(started_time)==hour & hour(ended_time)==hour ~ 1*minute(ended_time)-1*minute(started_time),
                        TRUE ~ 60)) %>%
  group_by(station_name, started_date, hour) %>%
  summarise(sum(minu))
```